# Issue with using [display-posts] shortcode with Visual Composer

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, visual-composer

I'm trying to add a list of recent posts in-line to WordPress pages using Visual Composer using the [display-posts] shortcode. However, whenever I do so, the title and link of the posts are displayed one column to the left of where they should be - the column I specify [display-posts] in just has either the date of the post (if requested with include_date="true"), or a blank bullet point (if not requested).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here. I attach some screenshots as examples.

Visual Composer set up - the list of posts should be in the right column...

[image: Visual Composer set up - the list of posts should be in the right column...]

Result on page - the lins and post titles seem to have spilled over to the left column...

[image: Result on page - the lins and post titles seem to have spilled over to the left column]

Thank you for your help

Comment: It seems like its CSS issue, you need to set display-post wrapper position relative and float:left, width:100%; surely your text will come into right column instead of overlapping the left.

Comment: Hi  - thanks for your help. I've created the following CSS for the page, and also modified the CSS reference in the display-posts item but it's still displaying incorrectly. The reference is working however, as if you change the width to 50%, the linked text moves to the right...

Any other thoughts?

.my-display-posts-format{
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
}

[display-posts category="embed-growth" posts_per_page=3 include_date="true" order="ASC" orderby="title" wrapper="div" wrapper_class="my-display-posts-format"]

Comment: thats strange it should work, can you please show me its firebug view how HTML structure is written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style in style.css actually .title class getting style from theme which conflicting with current structure with below code you can remove that.

```
.my-display-posts-format .listing-item .title{
    position:static;
    left:0;
}
```

It will surely work.